# Need tips for my friend's sick lab

Tags: dogs, health, eating, breeding

My best friend's lab is sick. She is vomiting, will not sleep, nor eat. I am really worried! She was just recently pregnant with 4 pups. Please help!

Comment: Tell your friend to go to the vet NOW.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend needs to take their dog to a vet immediately. If their regular veterinarian is not open, they should go to an emergency vet.